# number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float

Tags: php, laravel

Can you help me with the error:

```
number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/tutorial/laravel_lazday/resources/views/admin/master/product/create.blade.php)
```

I am getting this error in the code inside `create.blade.php` in `laravel` below:

```html
<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-body">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Nama Produk</dt>
                    <dd> {{ ucfirst($product ?? '') }}</dd>

                    <dt>Harga Produk</dt>
                    <dd> {{ "Rp. ". number_format($product ?? '',0,'.','.') }}</dd>

                    <dt>Stok Produk</dt>
                    <dd> <label for="" class="text text-primary"> {{ $product ?? ''->stock }} </label></dd>

                    {{-- <dt>Description</dt>
                    <dd style="word-break: break-all;"> {{ str_limit($product ?? ''->description,500,' ...') }}</dd> --}}

                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: @Sandeep errors are formatted as quote blocks.  And the php is not a runnable script.

Comment: did you `var_dump($product);` to see what the data is?  Why would you null coalesce to an empty string if a float is required?